# What motivates you in your work?

Tags: professional-practice

So, the general thread for answering about the "ultimate reason" for being in this field:

- Why do you do what you do?
- Why is it important?
- What is it for?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting that no-one has answered this yet! I'll try and answer as honestly as I can.

1. I think I do this because I enjoy project based work, doing something different everyday and enjoy the satisfaction of a complete soundtrack. I love seeing a piece of work from when I receive it, to how it is when I've finished it. It gives me a chance to be  constantly learning and improving.
2. I have struggled with this sometimes. Compared to the work of a doctor you could consider our work to be unimportant in many ways. I think it comes down to the project and the storytelling or message involved. I remember when I was younger watching the same films over and over (every night!), these films have shaped and affected who I am as a person and had a deep impact on how I view the world. Being part of this (especially audio!) is important to help entertain and inform others of a message clearly,artistically and professionally.
3. I think this question kinds of answers itself in number 2 and I think every project has a different purpose. Of course, not all projects are life changing, moral or even interesting stories. In this case it is an opportunity to use your studio, your gear and improve until you find that project that really means something to you and you'll be proud that you were part of the team involved.

Answer (score 3):

**Why do you do what you do?**

- To learn about the world, about life, about the human condition, about nature and about reality as we each individually perceive it, as well as the mass consensual hallucination of  our shared reality.
- As a means of creative expression
- To generate income to provide food, clothes and shelter (& the tools of my creative expression)

**Why is it important?**

- To create is an expression of being human, and our art, expression, meaning, ideas and emotions are all important parts of what make us each *uniquely* human.
- To develop and evolve as a sentient human being
- It allows me to eat, wear clothes and sleep indoors

**What is it for?**

- The communication of ideas and emotions

Answer (score 1):

"...musicians are willing to give their entire lives to a moment - to that melody, that lyric, that chord, or that interpretation that will stir the audience's soul. Musicians are beings who have tasted life's nectar in that crystal moment when they poured out their creative spirit and touched another's heart. In that instant, they were as close to magic, God, and perfection as anyone could ever be. And in their own hearts, they know that to dedicate oneself to that moment is worth a thousand lifetimes.”

- David Ackert, LA Times

Says musicians, but I insert sound editor (or designer).  All of the same family, just a different 'type' of musician at the end of the day.

Comment: Odd that he uses the phrase "are willing to give their entire lives to a moment". Sure we get the point, but it's not a life or death question is it? An interesting quote, nevertheless.

Comment: To each his own.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, I have no idea. But, I think what it really is is that it's almost not fully able to be realized in words. It drives me, no matter what. One of the few places I've found in life where no matter how bad things can get, I can still be smiling. I guess that's passion, or love, or whatever you want to call it. Calling, maybe.